# PHP undefined variable mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysql, variables, undefined

I have a mysql connection which is included in a separate file:

```
require 'settings.php';
```

and I have a file with all functions, also included:

```
require 'functions.php';
```

In the settings there it looks like this:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "passwort", "database");
    if(!$db) {
        exit("Error: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

and a function uses this connection like this:

```
function includehomepage() {
            $data = array();
            $query = "SELECT pagecontent FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = `0`";
            $query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
            return $data['pagecontent'];
        }
```

But I get an error message like this:

```
Undefined variable: db in /var/... on line 18
```

Do you have an answer? The variable have to be defined in the included file.. I am confused. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: In a function there's no `$db` variable unless u pass it as a parameter or declare as global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable scope problem. Look at [**`global`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
function includehomepage() {
   global $db;
   $data = array();
   $query = "SELECT pagecontent FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = '0'";
   $query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
   return $data['pagecontent'];
}
```

Comment: thank you! now there is just one more error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ..

Comment: Altered answer. Dont quote the 0 in "<backtick>". It'll think 0 is a column name, and kill the query. `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'`. Quote strings in `'`, or `"`.

Comment: You're welcome @fredkid. How this site works is to [accept an answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) once it's successfully answered your question, to "close" your question and to inform others what worked best for you. Both answers here are correct, please accept either one. :)

Comment: Please avoid using global vars. Use `function includehomepage($db) {...}` instead!

Answer (score 2):

$db is a global variable to `includehomepage` function. If you want to access it, then you have to pass it to the function or declare it as global inside the function.

like

```
function includehomepage() {
     global $db;   
     $data = array();
     $query = "SELECT pagecontent FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = '0'";
     $query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
     $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
     return $data['pagecontent'];
}
```

or have it as a parameter in your function and pass it via call.

```
function includehomepage($db) {
     $data = array();
     $query = "SELECT pagecontent FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = '0'";
     $query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
     $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
     return $data['pagecontent'];
}
includehomepage($db);
```